# In-Memory Database - How to Generate MVC Model classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-4, in-memory-database

I am very much new to MVC4 ASP.NET and In-memory databases. I apologize if my answer is too basic and stupid.
I have created an ASP.net MVC application that uses in-memory DB(SQLite3)by using

```
SQLiteConnection con=new SQLiteConnection(Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;);
```

I want to know that if database and its tables are created "in-memory", then how model and its classes will be generated so that i can use it in Controller/Views. In Memory database will be populated at runtime from certain XML.

**EDIT**

Here is how to create a table in memory

```
 using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:;"))
 {
     connection.Open();
     connection.CreateModule(new SQLiteModuleEnumerable("sampleModule", new string[] { "one", "two", "three" }));
     using (SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
     {
         command.CommandText ="CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t1 USING sampleModule;";
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     using (SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
     {
         command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t1;";
         using (SQLiteDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (dataReader.Read())
                 Console.WriteLine(dataReader[0].ToString());
         }
     }
     connection.Close();
 }
```

here is the C# SQLite Library: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: Are you saying that you know how to generate tables in the in-memory database, but you don't know how the models would be generated?

Comment: yes @JohnSaunders. I am unable to figure it out

Comment: And when you say "model", do you  mean an Entity Framework model, or just the "Model" classes for MVC?

Comment: I am developing MVC4 Application so it must be MVC Class Model

Comment: People, although this question was badly worded, it is not actually a request for a software recommendation. The OP has decided to use an in-memory database (which I presume means that he creates tables at runtime), and wonders how to generate the MVC models corresponding to the tables. No doubt all the examples he sees start with a database already created. I voted to re-open. Please do the same.

Comment: please show us an example of how you create tables in the database. We're not all familiar with in-memory databases.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for vote of reopen. i have provided simple and basic code of how to create table in-memory Database. Hope this helps

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I learned something new today!

Comment: Also, could you provide a link to the "SQLLite" library that you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low-tech way to solve this problem is to *not* generate model classes. Simply create them by hand to correspond to the part of the database you wish to work on in views. Remember that models are mostly meant for the use of the view - they should emphasize those things that the controller needs to pass to the view, and that the view needs to pass back to the controller. If they happen to mirror the database structure, then that's a bonus.

There may be some more-sophisticated ways of doing things, but I haven't used them. It's possible that you could create an Entity Framework Code First model, and use database migrations to actually create your in-memory tables. It's possible that you could then be lazy and use the exact same classes as the model that you pass to the views.

Better would be to have the Entity Framework classes worry about Entity Framework, and let the model classes worry about the views. Then use a tool like AutoMapper to copy data between the model passed to the view and the entity framework classes passed to the database.